# past value between buttons in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing an inventory management with codeignitor and can not keep track of the file type(stock in/stock out).

In my controller,I first defined $fileT as below.

```
class Inventory extends CI_Controller
{
 public $fileT='';
public function __construct()
{.....
```

When user visit localhost.com/ci/index/stockin, i wish to store the value (stockin) in $fileT,

```
 function index($fileType)
{       
$this->fileT=$fileType;
```

After user entered products to stock in, he should visit localhost.com/ci/save_order. Below is how I tried to access the fileT. But the result is nothing.

```
public function save_order()
{
   echo $this->fileT;
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When switching between URLs, CodeIgniter or even PHP won't be able to remember the values you save in an object. So, if we want our application to remember values when moving between different urls we need to save them in php `$_SESSION or $_COOKIE`. Let's change you code a bit:

localhost.com/ci/index/stockin

```
function index($fileType)
{       
    $_SESSION['fileType'] = $fileType;
}
```

localhost.com/ci/save_order

```
public function save_order()
{       
    if (isset($_SESSION['fileType']))
        echo $_SESSION['fileType'];
}
```

Your may then clear your $_SESSION['fileType'] after successful order save by using `unset($_SESSION['fileType'])`.